# How to pass data from one component to another via a function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How can I pass the data parameter from the openTeam function to another component in another file? The data can't change value, because it has an id in it that can't be changed. I am using functional components in my app.

```
const openTeam = (data) => {
        history.push("/" + data.name)
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Welcome />
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {teams.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <li onClick={() => openTeam(data)} key={data.teamId}>
                                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                                <p>{data.teamId}</p>
                            </li>
                        )
                        })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: How is that other component related to this component?  Is it one of the components being rendered here?

Comment: parent component?

Comment: The component will show the data for that team that is clicked on, and therefor I have to use data to retrieve the data from the database in the other component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data like this to navigated component

```
const openTeam = (data) => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/',
      state: { passedData: data }
    })
}
```

and access like this

```
this.props.location.state.passedData
```

Or or similarly for the `Link` component

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: '/',
   state: {passedData: data}
 }}> {data.name} </Link>
```

Comment: Do you have a method to use the data.name behind the / in the url? When I put it into both my Route and the Link, I can't access data.

Comment: @DanielOlsen to use 2nd one you need to configure react-router-route and import Link....can you share your code in codesandbox

Comment: I fixed the problem with the link. Thanks!